# Apply margin-left to all text lines of an html input button

Tags: css, input, margin-left

I cannot seem to align the text below the first line. See the text above the big green "send" button on the right of the page [link](https://www.apis.de/lp/english/training). I have tried display: margin-left:15px only works for the first line of text, but the rest displays differently.

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. Relevant code belongs into your question, not just on external sites.

Answer (score 1):

`margin-left: 15px;` works perfectly for me on the site you posted..
Just wrap the content you want moved in a div for example: margin-div and give the div `margin-left: 15px;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a grid like bootstrap for example. And separate your input (checkbox) from your text. Example in bootstrap :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2">your checkbox</div>
    <div class="col-xs-10">Your text</div>
</div>
```

Your don't have to use Bootsrap but a system of grid like that.

Hope that will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
.control-group.checkbox {
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.control-group.checkbox > input {
    margin-left: -23px;
}
```

This will move the whole `.control-group` to the right, but will revert it for the `input` elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to apply alignment you should enclose your text in a `<span></span>` or `<p></p>` and give `style="text-align:right;"`.

On the other hand if you are saying that you want text at an indentation(i.e. not text below the checkbox) then create a table there

```
           <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <p>I agree to the terms of the privacy policy of APIS Informationstechnologien GmbH to have my data stored and processed for the purposes of initiating business and improving customer service. My data will not be provided to third parties. At any time, I can disagree with APIS Informationstechnologien GmbH using the data.</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help someone else !

You can use display: block;

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ula/m04sj967/)

To achieve what you need using below css code is enough - apply this css class to what goes next to checkbox or radio button - BUT NOT for checkbox or radio input tag.

```
.blockText {
  display: block;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

If you also want radio button / checkbox to be vertically centered you can use these classes as well.

```
.parent {
    position: relative;
}

.child {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

HTML example is as follows:

```
<div class="parent">
<input class="child" type="checkbox" name="abc">
<span class="blockText">1. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam necessitatibus
            dignissimos saepe a molestiae, error cupiditate. Dolorem voluptates quae veniam vel ad iusto accusantium atque
            repellat? Qui omnis quia itaque!
 </span>
 </div>

 <br>

 <div class="parent">
 <input class="child" type="checkbox" name="abc2">
<span class="blockText">2. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam necessitatibus
            dignissimos saepe a molestiae, error cupiditate. Dolorem voluptates quae veniam vel ad iusto accusantium atque
            repellat? Qui omnis quia itaque!
 </span>
 </div>
```